# Indian living in France traveling to Morocco

Tags: indian-citizens, schengen-visas, morocco

I'm an Indian currently living in France. I have an Indian Passport and a French Titre de Séjour (Resident card) valid up to the end of 2019. I wish to travel to Morocco in May.

First of all, can I travel to Morocco with my French carte séjour? If not, what is the actual process? Can I apply for the Moroccan visa here in France?